# How to upload unknown file type?

Tags: uploads, media-library

I've already read about mime types in wordress and how to add them, but I can't find any documentation about the `correct type` of files. For e.g. after a lot of research I find out that the **epub** extension has a **application/epub+zip** file type, but how to get other unknown files like `.blend` or `.xcf` to work?

The following pseudocode illustrates the problem:

```
function custom_mime_types($mime_types){

    //Adding unknown extension 
    $mime_types['unknownextension'] = 'typeoffile'; 
    return $mime_types;
}

add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_mime_types', 1, 1);
```

Is there a Documentation about it?

Comment: check if this help? [get_allowed_mime_types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function as you mentioned and you need to learn your file extensions mime type (in example i add svg and xcf upload ability to wordpress)

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'ability_to_upload');

function ability_to_upload($mimes = array()) {
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $mimes['xcf'] = 'image/xcf';
    return $mimes;
}
```

Here is a link for [mime types list](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) and [file extension checker](http://filext.com/) (you can search by file extension)

Comment: Thanks Serkan, mime types list is helpfull! Sorry cant upvote you. But what about the blend-file?

Comment: You are welcome :) No problem with upvote, but you can select answer is right i think. i couldn't find blend file mime type either.

Comment: Comment after 3 years :D ```.blend``` mime-type is application/x-blender :)